# Using Hopper to flip branching instruction

Tags: arm

1. Is it possible to flip branch instruction such as tbz to tbnz and b.ne to b.eq, I tried the hopper it gives syntax error
2. Is it possible to set a NOP on a bl or equivalent instruction using Hopper so the application stop executing.
3. Is it possible to do #1, and #2 using Frida runtime script?